# Can you run an sdn across datacenters?

Tags: networking, datacenter

This is entirely for R&D purposes, not actual production use, for now. But can you run an sdn, say an overlay network for example, across datacenters? I.E. would I be able to run flannel on a single subnet across two datacenters?

Comment: Yeah, with the use of VXLANs. This will allow you to "tunnel" one VLAN or a set of VLANs through a VXLAN. It's exactly like VLAN nesting.

Comment: Yes, but just remember that you still can't break the speed of light.